# что делает метод componentWillMount в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не могу понять, что делает метод **componentWillMount** в React. В источниках сообщается, что он вызывается непосредственно перед монтированием компонента в DOM. А зачем, не понятно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `componentWillMount()` можно вызвать `setState()`. Но это не рекомендуется. Можно было бы использовать сайд-эффекты, но и этого просят избегать. И вообще, если заглянуть в документацию, то его переименовывают в `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`. Так что метод не особо полезный, и использовать его нежелательно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> что делает метод componentWillMount

он - ничего, а вот то что ты в него поместишь и выполнится

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div id="qwa">qwa</div>)
    }
    componentWillMount() { }
    componentdidmount() {
        const qwa = document.getElementById('qwa')
        //   -,-
    }
}
```

## если понимаешь в JS:

по аналогии

то же самое что и код ниже - аналог(componentdidmount), только перед

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const el = document.getElementById('elID')
    // -,-
    // ...
})
```

или

[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Web_Components/Использование_пользовательских_элементов#Использование_lifecycle_callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Web_Components/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_lifecycle_callbacks)

### устарел

> Примечание:
>
> Этот метод устарел. Не используйте его в новом коде.

так посчитал фэйсбук, если вы с ним не согласны:

- можно и дальше использовать старую версию реакт
- есть ещё и такие библиотеки как https://preactjs.com/